# Emited Solidity Events not being watched at frontend truffle contract instance

Tags: solidity, truffle, javascript, events, frontend

So, I have been reading through A LOT of pages about events in Solidity and how to interact with them on frontend but I am still pretty new to this and it seems like there have been multiple changes, since many sites I saw used outdated methods to watch for Solidity event changes. I had it working at some point but it then suddenly stopped working for no apparent reason.

I tried this with all of my 4 Solidity events, for simplicity sake, I will only show my example with one method

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Platoonfactory {
    event PlatoonCreated(address owner, uint256 platoonId);

    uint256 public currentPlatoonID = 1;
    uint256 public contractBalance = address(this).balance;

    /**
     * A platoon has atleast one truck driving in front and 0..n trucks following
     */
    struct Platoon {
        uint256 platoonId;
        address payable owner;
        uint costPerMinute;
        uint startDate;
        uint endDate;
        // participants contains all joined trucks inside this platoon
        mapping(uint /* index */ => TruckInPlatoon) participants;
        uint participantsSize;
    }

    /**
     * A TruckInPlatoon struct describes exactly one truck inside a platoon *besides* the leaders
     */
    struct TruckInPlatoon {
        uint platoonId;
        address truckOwner;
        uint startDate;
        uint allowedParticipationUntilDate;
        uint payedAmountOfWei;
    }

    // map the owner of a platoon to the unique ID
    mapping(address => uint) public platoonOwners;
    // map the unique ID to each platoon
    mapping(uint => Platoon) public platoons;


    /**
     * Create a new platoon with required cost to join and the amount of hours in which this platoon is available
     */
    function createPlatoon(uint cpm, uint endDate) public returns (uint) {
        require(platoonOwners[msg.sender] == 0, "You have already started a platoon");
        require(endDate >= 1, "Platoon must at least be available for one hour");

        // create a new platoon and push it to the storage
        platoons[currentPlatoonID] = Platoon({platoonId: currentPlatoonID, owner: msg.sender, costPerMinute: cpm, startDate: now, endDate: (now + endDate*3600), participantsSize:0});
        platoonOwners[msg.sender] = currentPlatoonID;

        //Increment current ID
        currentPlatoonID++;

        // fire event
        emit PlatoonCreated(msg.sender, currentPlatoonID);
        return currentPlatoonID - 1;
    }

}
```

JavaScript:

```
App = {
    contracts: {},
    address: "",
    web3js: null,
    PlatoonContract: null,

    init: function () {
        return App.initWeb3();
    },

    initWeb3: function () {
        if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
            App.web3js = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        } else {
            App.web3js = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:7545"));
        }
        return App.initHTML();
    },

    initHTML: function () {
        App.web3js.eth.getAccounts((err, accounts) => {
            if (!err) {
                document.getElementById("account-id").innerHTML = accounts[0];
                App.address = accounts[0];
            } else {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
        return App.initContract();
    },

    initContract: function () {
        $.getJSON('../build/contracts/Platoonfactory.json', function (data) {
            var PlatoonArtifact = data;
            App.contracts.Platoonfactory = TruffleContract(PlatoonArtifact);
            App.contracts.Platoonfactory.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);

            App.contracts.Platoonfactory.deployed().then(function (instance) {
                App.PlatoonContract = instance;
                return App.listenFor();
            });
        });
    },

    listenFor: function () {
        App.PlatoonContract.PlatoonCreated({}, {fromBlock:0, toBlock: 'latest'}).watch(function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }

            if (result) {
                console.log(result);
                document.getElementById("platoonList").innerText = "ID: " + res.args.platoonId.c[0] + " Owner: " + res.args.owner;
            }
        });
        return App.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function () {
        $("#btnCreatePlatoon").click(event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            let cpm = document.getElementById("costPerMinute").value;
            let duration = document.getElementById("hoursAvailable").value;
            App.PlatoonContract.createPlatoon(cpm, duration);
        });

        $("#btnContractBalance").click(event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            App.PlatoonContract.contractBalance().then(result => console.log(result.c[0]));
        });
    },

};

$(function () {
    $(window).load(function () {
        App.init();
    });
});
```

The HTML shouldn't matter in this case. I have been trying to fix this since nearly a week and started to get crazy about this already since there are so many outdated posts. I would be extremely thankfull if one could finally find what's going wrong. I tested the Solidity code in Remix and all methods worked fine and Ganache even recognized the events at the Contract Tab, the error seems to lay at the point I am attaching the listener.

ADDITION: I am using Truffle, Ganache and Metamask to test my DApp

Comment: What version of web3 are you using? Is Metamask connected to Ganache? Is transaction executed successfully? I'd start commenting out or disable stuff until thing start to work again.

Comment: @Ismael thanks for responding. I am using web3 @ 2.0.0-alpha.1 which is the current pre-release. Metamask is connected to Ganache and transactions all succeed and can be seen in Ganache. I already disabled everything to the core of executing that function and listening to the event. At this point I have no idea what to exclude additionally. Could you try to run my code at your build to verify there is no error in my configurations?

Comment: Your code appears to be correct. You are using an alpha version of web3 so I'd start trying a more stable version.

Comment: @Ismael I fixed the code by removing the toBlock parameter. I am not completely sure why Metamask didn't quite like that but at least it's working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed it finally! It seems like the 2nd parameter in the event handler which which specified fromBlock and toBlock is not compatible with Metamask. It worked after I removed the toBlock parameter. Working snippet:

```
App.PlatoonContract.PlatoonCreated({}, {fromBlock:0}).watch(function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }

        if (result) {
            console.log(result);
            document.getElementById("platoonList").innerText = "ID: " + res.args.platoonId.c[0] + " Owner: " + res.args.owner;
        }
    });
```